# Existence proof : $\forall x\in \Bbb R \wedge x\geqq-3 \ \ \exists y \in \Bbb R : \frac{y(y-6)}{3}=x \\ $

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

Prove that for every real number x with $x\geqq -3$ there exists a real number y such that $  \frac{y(y-6)}{3}=x $

$\forall x\in \Bbb R \wedge x\geqq-3 \ \ \exists y \in \Bbb R :  \frac{y(y-6)}{3}=x \\ $

To prove this directly I must solve the equation for y and then plug the result into the left side of the equation to show that it holds for x.

However, I have a problem solving this equation for y.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried completing the square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this quadratic:

$y^2-6y-3x=0$

The discriminant of which is 36+12x. In order for $y$ to have real solutions, the discriminant has to be at least zero which means what about $x$? That is most of the hard part done.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of y, it's just a quadratic equation,
nothing special. You should be able to solve it
(for y) in the usual way.

See e.g. [Quadratic Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation)